# PHP - Filter URLs from a user's message to include links from the parent website only

Tags: php, regex, url, yii

I am working on a message filtering algorithm to allow links from the parent website and replace even the minutest trace of links from an external website in any form.

Would appreciate a wholesome solution on the same from the perspective of PHP.

From what I know, this can be accomplished 4 in basic steps -
**1. Detect URLS in the string using preg_match_all

2. Sanitize them to valid URL formats

3. Use parse_url to check the host value and replace the old string appropriately.

4.Convert urls to html friendly clickable links.**

Also, I am using the Yii framework if it helps.

Edit : Pasting my code here, suggestions are welcome.

```
       $pattern = '(?xi)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`\!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))';
       $message = preg_replace_callback("#$pattern#i", function($matches) {
       $hostname = Yii::app()->params['baseUrlName'];
       $input = $matches[0];
       $url = preg_match('!^https?://!i', $input) ? $input : "http://$input";
       $data = parse_url($url);
       if(isset($data['host']) && $data['host']==$hostname)
        { return '<a href="' . $url . '" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">' .     "$input</a>"; } 
       else
        { return ' x '; }    }, $message);
```

Comment: Those basic steps sound pretty good. What is your question, what are you stuck with?

Comment: Not stuck with the current approach per se, just concerned about this getting too cumbersome over long messages and was hoping for an alternate shorter and more efficient solution if available through PHP.

Comment: I don't think there is a straightforward PHP feature for this. It'll likely grow *more* complicated if you want to catch cases like relative URLs (which are OK under your rule), protocol-relative ones (which you'd check for where they point...)

Comment: Yes the regex for the first step comes out to be pretty long. Any alternate solution would still be awesome to know :)

Comment: Updated my question with the solution as of now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently the best solution to go about it.

```
       $pattern = '(?xi)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:(?P<BPC>[^\s()<>]+)|\(((?&BPC)|(\((?&BPC)\)))*\))+(?:\(((?&BPC)|(\((?&BPC)\)))*\)|[^\s`\!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))';
       $message = preg_replace_callback("#$pattern#i", function($matches) {
       $hostname = Yii::app()->params['baseUrlName'];
       $input = $matches[0];
       $url = preg_match('!^https?://!i', $input) ? $input : "http://$input";
       $data = parse_url($url);
       if(isset($data['host']) && $data['host']==$hostname)
        { return '<a href="' . $url . '" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">' .     "$input</a>"; } 
       else
        { return ' x '; }    }, $message);
```

Update - edited with the regex tweak from Alex.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an image of the `$pattern`:

```
(?xi)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`\!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

It can be reduced like this:

```
(?xi)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:(?P<BPC>[^\s()<>]+)|\(((?&BPC)|(\((?&BPC)\)))*\))+(?:\(((?&BPC)|(\((?&BPC)\)))*\)|[^\s`\!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: the reduction makes sense, thanks.